# Apache on Windows Virtualhost: works on IE or Edge, but unable to connect on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: windows, apache, google-chrome, firefox, virtualhost

I never had problems with multiple Virtualhosts on Apache, not on Windows nor BSD.

My secondary virtualhost gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome. 
"httpd -S" gives me no errors and a good config, this got me thinking, so I tried "curl -v", which was successful, then I tried IE and EDGE and they are working fine.

I tried to empty Chrome DNS cache, there are no Apache logs for the connections made from Chrome or FF, but there are log entries from 'localhost' and that's accessible from all and produces the logs from all browsers.

I'm kind of curious now, what is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I forgot to mention: I used .dev for tld on my virtualhost, and I won't do it anymore. Here is why:

> Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.
>
> Update 07/02/2018: Firefox now also forces .DEV domains to HTTPS.

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Conclusion: If you configure your .dev domain for ssl then there is no way to make an exception (firefox or chrome). So no more dev domains for local development, for me at least.